# wso2 for server tot server authentication

Tags: .net-core, wso2

I am new to wso2 and I am trying to find out how I can use wso2 to authenticate servers to API.

On the server I get an bearer token by [Client credential grant](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/access-delegation/client-credentials-playground/)
This returns an access_token.

```
using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token");
var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{clientKey}:{clientSecret}"));
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");
request.Content = new StringContent($"grant_type=client_credentials");
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

using var response = httpClient.Send(request);
using var content = response.Content.ReadAsStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(content);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

var credentials = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClientCredentials>(text);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", credentials.access_token);
```

I add this to the API

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.Authority = "https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token";
    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true
    };
});
```

Now I get the error:

```
Status: 500
Response: 
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '26-10-2023 08:37:02 +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationE
```

However if I go directly to the url [localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token/.well-known/openid-configuration) it works.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your overall use case?

Comment: @chashikajw I have updated the question